# How to validate user input ang HTML positions using Selenium?

Tags: validation, selenium

I am studying selenium as part of my project. And I am really a beginner and I have a difficulty in understanding some commands in selenium.

I know how to find the locations of ID, and using type commands and assertion. But I don't know **how can I validate user input if required or not** and **How can i create a test for HTML positioning?**

For example I have 3 tabs. First is the General tab second is the Information tab and last is the Extras tab. How can I validate the order of tabs?

```
My example validation is:
Verify if Information tab is after the General tab
```

What are the commands I need for this type of validation?

That's all guys I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please add some HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking, but `Webdriver` `findElements` method is returning the list of `WebElement`'s in the order that they are in markup. So given that you have in markup:

```
<a lang="de" href="//de.wikipedia.org/">Deutsch</a>
<a lang="en" href="//en.wikipedia.org/">English</a>
<a lang="es" href="//es.wikipedia.org/">Español</a>
```

and you query it into the `List<WebElement>` they will be in the order 1. Deutsch 2. English 3. Español

For example, try running this code to see the order :

```
@Test
public void doSomething(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"langlist langlist-large\"]//a"));
    for (WebElement element : elements){
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can get the location of element by using `element.getLocation()` and compare the X and Y coordinate. Something like (assuming general tab is on top of information tab:

```
int y1 = informationTab.getLocation().getY();
int y2 = generalTab.getLocation().getY();
assertTrue(y2 < y1);
```